# WordPress load javascript file if something... (after the page is loaded)

Tags: php, functions, jquery, javascript, cookies

I'm having an issue with making a website GDPR ready. It is loading a javascript file for InstraGram that is setting a cookie.

I was able to locate where this file is loaded in the plug-in directory but I dont want to edit this file because after that I cant update anymore.

So I was able to dequeue the script so it wont be loaded.

After that I tried everything to load the file conditionaly after the page is loaded. So when you accept the Cookies then the script wil be loaded.

This is the if statement and last thing I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CookiebotCallback_OnAccept() {
        if (Cookiebot.consent.marketing)
        {
        $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/js/sb-instagram.min.js"><\/script>');
        };
}
</script>
```

But I am starting to wonder more and more whether it is possible to load afterwards?

Somebody has done something like this before?

Comment: It would depend on how the original JS was built. If it's set to trigger at a certain point that has already passed, nothing will happen. Regardless this is really a JS question, so you might be better off asking at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You should probably also raise this with the developer of the plugin, as something they might be able to address.

Answer (score 0):

**try now this code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CookiebotCallback_OnAccept() 
{
    if (Cookiebot.consent.marketing)
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/js/sb-instagram.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you example. I tried this but nothing happens. For your reference, I'm placing this code in the footer.php of my child theme so maybe the path to the file is not correct?

Comment: put a full path such as "<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/js/sb-instagram.min.js"